# Composer and git tags with a slash

Tags: git, composer-php

I have a project that requires a tagged release of a git library (namely, woocommerce/storefront). They have tagged their versions like this: `version/1.0.0`,  `version/1.1.0`,  `version/1.1.1` etc.

I'm finding it impossible to get Composer to pull in these releases due to parsing errors:

```
composer update

    [UnexpectedValueException]
    Could not parse version constraint version/2.3.1: Invalid version string "version/2.3.1"

    Failed to update packages for  ./composer.json.
```

The relevant part of my composer.json file is as follows:

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "git@github.com:woocommerce/storefront.git"
    }
  ],
  "require-dev": {
    "woocommerce/storefront": "version/2.3.1"
  }
}
```

I'm getting the impression that it's invalid simply because Composer is expecting a version number like 1.2.3, without `version/` prefixed. Is there any way to tell Composer to find the versions in the versions directory?

Comment: How Composer works with VCS revisions: [Versions and constraints- Composer Versions vs VCS Versions](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#composer-versions-vs-vcs-versions). And the tags with `version/` prefixes are gone in the `woocommerce/storefront` git repository.

Answer (score 1):

You may use commit hash to point to this version:

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "git@github.com:woocommerce/storefront.git"
    }
  ],
  "require-dev": {
    "woocommerce/storefront": "dev-master#18e066bdecaeb5b779b3db7b896bb3fbcbac8d65 as 2.3.1"
  }
}
```

You may also consider using [wpackagist](https://wpackagist.org/) for WordPress packages:

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://wpackagist.org"
    }
  ],
  "require-dev": {
    "wpackagist-theme/storefront":"2.3.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, but doesn't answer my question. I have discovered in any case that I need an actual clone of the repo, not just the release version - so it is a moot point.